# produce an array or list of values from a select HTML widget

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, watir, watir-webdriver

Similar to

```
selectContent = browser.select_list(:id, "lstStrike0_1").options.map(&:text)
```

is there a way to get a list or array of *values* (as in the **value="..."** attribute for each select option in HTML)?

Directly or indirectly? 
I looked up http://jarib.github.com/watir-webdriver/doc/Watir/Select.html but see no `.values`
analogous to the `.options` method.

EXAMPLE

```
<select id="lstExpMonth0_0"   name="lstExpMonth0_0">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="7/27/2012;0">JulWk4</option>
<option value="8/18/2012;1">Aug12</option>
<option value="9/22/2012;1">Sep12</option>
```

Thus

```
browser.select_list(:id, "lstExpMonth0_0").options.map(&:text)
```

gets me

```
=> ["JulWk4", "Aug12", "Sep12"]
```

How can I end up instead with the collection or array:

```
["7/27/2012;0", "8/18/2012;1", "9/22/2012;1"]
```

*regardless* of what might be selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
browser.select_list(:id, "lstExpMonth0_0").options.map(&:value)
=> ["", "7/27/2012;0", "8/18/2012;1", "9/22/2012;1"]
```

All elements have the `value()` method, which will return the value of the value attribute.

Comment: Indeed. That hit me soon after posting the question. Sometimes writing it up helps